# Cert-Manager Order stuck on pending/ Ingress invalid Required value: port name or number is required

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

Working on setting up cert-manager with letsencrypt for a cluster, its my first go around with it, but I followed the directions from [cert-manager for nginx](https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/nginx-ingress/#step-5---deploy-cert-manager). For the most part, it seems like it is going through on the cert-manager end, but failing with letsencrypt in approving the certificate order.

The certificate request shows that the order is still pending:

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-09-27T17:17:01Z
    Message:               Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
    Reason:                cert-manager.io
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Approved
    Last Transition Time:  2023-09-27T17:17:01Z
    Message:               Waiting on certificate issuance from order demoapp/letsencrypt-prod-ddwx4-3613889838: "pending"
    Reason:                Pending
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

And describe on the order shows:

```
Status:
  Authorizations:
    Challenges:
      Token:        #token
      Type:         http-01
      URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/268518448916/V2yLwg
      Token:        #token
      Type:         dns-01
      URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/268518448916/T3zphQ
      Token:        #token
      Type:         tls-alpn-01
      URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/268518448916/XS_lSg
    Identifier:     app.example.net
    Initial State:  pending
    URL:            https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/268518448916
    Wildcard:       false
  Finalize URL:     https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/finalize/1330861946/211267025816
  State:            pending
  URL:              https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/1330861946/211267025816
Events:             <none>
```

Following a suggestion from another post, I ran the dns query through [unboundtest.com](https://unboundtest.com), and it seems the validation on the dns went through, heres the last 3 lines of the log:

```
Sep 27 23:53:31 unbound[1511300:0] info: validated DNSKEY example.net. DNSKEY IN
Sep 27 23:53:31 unbound[1511300:0] info: validate(nodata): sec_status_secure
Sep 27 23:53:31 unbound[1511300:0] info: validation success app.example.net. CAA IN
```

From reading different posts on here, it seems that likely it is a port setup issue on the ingress, but as far as I can tell, there are no issues there. I have a frontend running on port 3000, backend on 5000. The site is working fine over http, no port/ routing concerns other than trying to get the https set. Host name is for different environments, prod/staging, but again, they line up with the DNS, namespace, and everything is running fine from the web, just not the https setup. Heres the ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "{{ .Values.cert.issuer.name }}"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: “HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,X-LANG,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-Api-Key,X-Device-Id,Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
  
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
    secretName: {{ .Values.cert.acme.secretkey }}
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.frontend.service.name }}
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.frontend.service.ports.port }} #3000
              targetPort: http
            port:
              number: 443
              targetPort: https
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.backend.service.name }}
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.backend.service.ports.port }} #5000
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

Thinking maybe I had an issue with the port setup, I tried changing to:

```
ports:
  - port: 
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: {{ .Values.frontend.service.ports.port }}
  - port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
```

but doing that, and variations along those lines, gets me this error when trying to run the helm upgrade:

```
W0928 17:03:02.094142 1192382 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.service.ports"
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "ingress-service" with kind Ingress: Ingress.extensions "ingress-service" is invalid: spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend: Required value: port name or number is required
```

also added these annotations based on an answer from another post:

```
acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
acme.cert-manager.io/http01-ingress-class: "nginx"
```

Please let me know if there is something I missed, set up wrong, overlooked, or if you have any suggestions on how to further debug. Thanks

Also, I'm running on GKE, if that makes a difference.